# Is fever a disease or not?

Tags: pathology

I have seen [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7541) where the author is asking why people take drugs for fever. So my question is: Is fever is a disease or not?

Comment: Fever is due to increase in the levels of some cytokines (IL 1 - being most common cause) in the body. These cytokines generally (speaking broadly) are secreted by either immune cells or injured cells. So when there is a large scale immune response or injury, the response is Fever. So Fever is a symptom showing what is happening inside the body

Answer (score 3):

I know pretty much nothing in medicine!

[Fever](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fever#Signs_and_symptoms) is an abnormally high body temperature. Fever is a symptom and not a disease *per se*. Different medical conditions (incl. various infectious diseases) causes a patient to have fever.

Note that fever might be in some/most situations an adaptive response to a disease. In other words, for infectious disease causing fever, fever might be good for the host and not for the parasite. However this issue remains controversial (see [the post linked in the OP's question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7541/if-fever-is-a-natural-immune-defense-why-do-people-take-drugs-to-lower-it) for more info).

As GoodGravy said in the comments, many people get confused and consider fever as a disease instead of what it really is; a symptom. One likely reason for this confusion is that when one has fever, (s)he very often treat fever directly (taking drugs like [Aspirin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirin) for example) rather than treating the underlying cause (the virus for example) of the fever.

Comment: I agree, but furthermore to end the confusion: Fever is the symptom of an underlying disease/infection, but it is very treatable and often is treated rather than the underlying cause of the fever. I think the fact that the fever is treated rather than the infection is what causes confusion. Although if you were to be pedantic I suppose you are not in an eased state due to the fever so I guess semantically you are in "dis-ease" directly because of the fever... Let me think a while...

Answer (score 0):

Any malfunctioning in the body is the result of either external pathogens, environmental changes or it can be manifested by the body itself. Based on which we can call it a disease or a disorder.

Some can be viewed with the help of its underlying symptoms. Fever is a natural response of the human body to any kind of imbalance, for example, temperature fluctuations, infections, etc., and that is why we can get fever by any number of reasons. What is important is that it shows us of some other underlying reason of change. Therefore I think it's more of a symptom than a disease.